# What would be the proper way to combine 2 rows in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

So I have this table called test.

```
A       B   C
dude    10  10
cool    10  10
other   10  10
```

And I want to combine 2 rows based on column a.

So if I were too merge "dude" and "cool" I would end up with something like this. Removing the second name. I do realize that I may have to do a second call to remove the old row.

```
A       B   C
dude    20  20
other   10  10
```

And I thinking about this wrong to do a update statement with nested selects?

I tried something like this to see if I could just merge the b column.

```
Update test Set b = al.newb
  FROM
  (
    SELECT b as newb 
    FROM test WHERE a = "cool"
  ) al
Where a = "dude";
```

Here is a sql fiddle call to create the table if needed.

```
Create Table test (a varchar(10), b int(3), c int(3));

Insert into test (a, b, c) values ("dude", 10, 10);
Insert into test (a, b, c) values ("cool", 10, 10);
Insert into test (a, b, c) values ("other", 10, 10);
```

I cant seem to get really anything to work.

Comment: Is this for Oracle's MySQL or Microsoft's SQL Server?  Those are different relational databases.  Is there some reason that `cool` is being merged into `dude`, or is it totally arbitrary?  The two don't seem related at all.  Is column A a key field or unique identifier?

Comment: Basicly I need to merge 2 people with different names into one row. If that makes since. And its Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with a `select`:

```
select (case when a in ('cool', 'dude') then 'dude' else a end) as a,
       sum(b) as b, sum(c) as c
from test
group by (case when a in ('cool', 'dude') then 'dude' else a end);
```

If you want to modify the data in place, an `update` will not do because you need to delete a row.  I would recommend inserting the above query results into a temporary table, truncating the original table, and re-inserting the rows that you want.